# Issues with Cross-Origin using flask and ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, cors

I'm having some issues with the "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". I tried to allow first from the server, than from all ("*"). Got every time the same error message on the chrome developer toolkit.

Here is my flask python code:

```
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object(__name__)
cors = CORS(application, resorces={r'/*': {"origins": '*'}})

@application.route("/get-live-data",methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def live_data():
    con = connect_db()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * from envoiContinuT")
    sqlite_result = cur.fetchall()
    cle = json.load(open(JSON_STATUS))
    parametres = json.load(open(JSON_PARAMETRES))
    descT = []
    for key in cle["status"]:
        attr = parametres[key]
        if attr["envoiC"] == 1:
            descT.append(attr["description"])
    response = any_response(flask.jsonify(data=descT))
    return response
```

Here is my Ajax code:

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";

function getLiveData(data){
    //Get the parameters descriptions
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url:baseURL + '/get-live-data',
        headers: {
            "Accept" : "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //populateAccordion(data);    
        },

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); 
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
    });
}
```

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
cors = CORS(application, resorces={r'/*': {"origins": '*'}})
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Should be:

```
cors = CORS(application, resources={r'/*': {"origins": '*'}})
```

Also, there’s no point in sending a `Content-type` request header for *`GET` request*. There’s no request body for `GET` requests, so no need to specify a content type. So instead just do this:

```
headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
},
```

Otherwise, if you send a `Content-Type` request header with the value `application/json`, that triggers your browser to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), and your config must allow it:

```
@application.route("/get-live-data",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type']) # Send Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

But if you allow the `Content-Type` request header, you might as well allow `POST` requests too (as above)—since as mentioned earlier here, there’s no point in allowing it just for `GET` requests.

Comment: while using flask_restplus all I had to do was to create an object of `CORS(...)` and use `"Accept": "application/json" ` and it works like charm (y)